# How to transfer saved passwords between two different Firefox installation?

Tags: firefox, password-management, portable-apps

I am currently using a `portable` installation of Firefox 3.6.13, set to save passwords for some sites, using the Master Password feature.

Now, I would like to move all my saved passwords to another Firefox portable installation (4.x Beta). How can I do this?

**EDIT:** If you suggest alternatives, please suggest solutions that implement the concept of **Master Password**. This has to be requested every time I launch Firefox, before allowing usage of saved passwords.

Comment: Have you tried the "Password Exporter" add-on with 4B?

Answer (score 2):

You could sync both instances using the Firefox Sync Addon [Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefox-sync/)

Comment: Can I set Firefox Sync Addon to ask me for Master Password before allow using stored password?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) to synchronise Bookmarks, Passwords, Open tabs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LastPass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lastpass-password-manager/) to accomplish this.

One notable advantage of LastPass is that you can access your passwords through a Web interface.